# Execute shortcode in a toggle button

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, shortcode

In a WordPress website I have a shortcode that update a field of a form via a a link (update value of entry in database).

**My first shortcode** (update the value to Yes): `[entry-update-field id=[id] field_id=208 value="Yes" label="List your entry!" class="classmadevisible"]` -> Result in a WordPress page is: [List your entry!](https://www.example.com)

**My second shortcode** (update the value to No): `[entry-update-field id=[id] field_id=208 value="No" label="Stop list your entry!" class="classnotvisible"]` -> Result in a WordPress page is: [Stop list your entry!!](https://www.example.com)

If I click on this links it update the value of a field (entry) in database, to Yes or No.

**My question is:** it is possible to execute this shortocodes (links) via a Toggle button? If toggle is inactive to execute No (second shortcode), and if toggle button is active to execute Yes (first shortocode).

```css
    .onoffswitch {
        position: relative; 
        width: 45px;
        -webkit-user-select:none; 
        -moz-user-select:none; 
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label {
        display: block; 
        overflow: hidden; 
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 16px; 
        padding: 0; 
        line-height: 16px;
        border: 0px solid #CCCCCC; 
        border-radius: 26px;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label:before {
        content: "";
        display: block; 
        width: 26px; 
        margin: -5px;
        background: #F70303;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        bottom: 0;
        right: 25px;
        border-radius: 26px;        
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label {
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label, .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
       border-color: #E0E0E0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
        right: 0px; 
        background-color: #3DA10F;        
    }
```

```html
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very dirty way, but:

```
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>

        <div class="state-shortcodes" style="display: none">
                <div class="on-state-shortcode">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[entry-update-field id=[id] field_id=208 value="Yes" label="List your entry!" class="classmadevisible"]'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="off-state-shortcode">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[entry-update-field id=[id] field_id=208 value="No" label="Stop list your entry!" class="classnotvisible"]'); ?>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $('.onoffswitch').on('input.onoffswitch-checkbox', 'change', function(){
        let state = $(this).prop("checked") == true ? 'on' : 'off';
        $(this).closest('.onoffswitch').find('.' + state + '-state-shortcode a').trigger('click');
    })
});
</script>
```